# Question about Inner product in polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, inner-products

Let  $V=\{p(x); \partial(p(x)<2\} \cup\{0\}$ a vector space, determine a inner product such that the basis $\{1,x,\frac{x^2}{2!}\}$ is orthonormal.

My solution:

I found the inner product: $<a_0 + a_1x+a_2x^2, b_0+b_1x+b_2x^2> = a_0b_0 + a_1b_1 + 4a_2b_2.$

this way we have $\{1,x,\frac{x^2}{2!}\}$  orthonormal basis...

But I would to solve this exercise using integrals or differential equations, how I do it?

Comment: $\partial$ is not a standard notation for the degree of  a polynomial and you certainly mean $\partial(p) \leq 2$ when you wrote $\partial(p) < 2$. Also, $0$ is already a polynomial of degree at most $2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given $p(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2$, we have $p(0) = a_0$, $p'(0) = a_1$, and $p''(0) = 2a_2$. Hence,
$$\langle p, q \rangle = p(0)q(0) + p'(0)q'(0) + p''(0)q''(0).$$

Comment: thank you, like taylor polynomial

Comment: Exactly! Note that they wrote $\frac{x^2}{2!}$, instead of the (simpler) $\frac{x^2}{2}$.